# Check if User is Logged in on Firebase Auth from Node.js (Cloud Functions)

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create an Express dynamic web page on Node.js. I want to perform the following logic on the server (Firebase Cloud Functions) at path `/`:

- If the client is logged in (Firebase Auth), render the home page `my_home_page.html`
- If the client is not logged in, render the login page `my_login_page.html`

So I need to implement the `isClientLoggedIn` function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();

export const redirects = functions.https.onRequest(app);

app.set('views', './res');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

function isClientLoggedIn(request: Request): bool {
    return // ???
}
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (isClientLoggedIn(req)) {
        res.render('my_home_page.html');
    } else {
        res.render('my_login_page.html');
    }
});
```

However, I have checked the Firebase Auth documentation and I do not know how to implement this function. Is it possible to check the clients' login state from the HTTP request, or are there other ways to render the correct content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way in HTTPS-triggered Cloud Functions to know if the request came from a user that is signed in. If you want to be able to determine that, you'll need to pass the user's ID token along with the request, and decode and verify that token in the Cloud Function. For a simple example of this, see [Authenticated JSON API](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api) in the `function-samples` repo.

Comment: Then what are some common techniques on home pages used by websites, say Stack Overflow?

Comment: I can't tell you how Stack Overflow implements its user authentication, but it will always be some variant of what I described in my answer.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but (unless I'm mistaken) it is possible now, with CallableFunctions which you can register with `onCall`.

Comment: OP uses `functions.https.onRequest(app);`, which does not support that feature.